# Is this an it-cleft with bare infinitive?

Tags: bare-infinitive

> "Actually, we didn't get lost," the tall one says. "We
>   ran away."
>      "Not running away so much as just
>   stumbling onto this spot and deciding to stay put," the brawny one
>   adds. "That's different from getting lost."
>      "Not
>   just anybody can find this place," the tall soldier says. "But we did,
>   and now you have too. It was a stroke of luck--for us, at least."
>      "If we hadn't found this spot, they would've shipped us
>   overseas," the brawny one ex-plains. "Over there it was **kill or be
>   killed**. That wasn't for us. I'm a farmer, originally, and my buddy
>   here just graduated from college. Neither one of us wants to kill
>   anybody. And being killed's even worse. Kind of obvious, I'd
>   say."
>      "How 'bout you?" the tall one asks me. "Would
>   you like **to kill anybody, or be killed**?"
>  (Kafka on the Shore, tr.
>   by Philip Gabriel)

Why does the first phrase have bare infinitive? 
(If the first be an it-cleft, [CGEL](http://www.cambridge.org/uk/linguistics/cgel/) says the type is normally inadmissible (p.1422), and Bas Aarts also says in his book to infinitives are allowable not in it-cleft but only in pseudo-cleft.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first phrase is not an it-cleft, which is clear from the complete lack of a subordinating clause. An it-cleft is  *it + be + X[usually NP] + subordinate clause*

> it + was + the fall from the cliff + that killed him

Note that an it-cleft does not have a to-infinitive.

*[kill or be killed](http://www.idiomquest.com/learn/idiom/kill-or-be-killed/)* is an idiomatic phrase, a single lexical unit sometimes called a [Siamese Twin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siamese_twins_%28linguistics%29), that describes a situation. The first phrase is actually a simple declarative sentence "It was X" describing a situation or state.

> It was crowded
>
> It was dangerous
>
> It was noisy
>
> It was do or die
>
> It was kill or be killed

The second phrase is part of a question, asking "Would you like to X?" As it is asking about a like, it has a to-infinitive.

> Would you like to eat?
>
> Would you like to sleep?
>
> Would you like to kill?

To-infinitives are commonly used when talking about thoughts or feelings:

> He chose/wanted/decided/liked/hated/expected/hoped/etc to shoot his enemy

Comment: and a play on the set phrase used earlier

Comment: Excellent answer. OP's library sounds impressive too. I'd just throw in 'It was time to go' as an apparent counterexample - I suppose 'time to go' is unitary (X rather than X + to-infinitive).

Answer (score 1):

“Kill or be killed” is a **set phrase** and could easily be set off with quotes or italicised in that passage.

[Dictionarist.com](http://www.dictionarist.com/kill+or+be+killed) has:

> **kill or be killed**
>   one must protect oneself, it is preferable to kill someone instead of allowing them to kill you

The brawny one explained that over there, they either had to kill someone or be killed themselves.

Grammatically, although *kill* is uninflected in the set phrase it’s probably better parsed as imperative than infinitive.

An “it-cleft” sentence **starts** with *it* and presents two pieces of information which could be presented in a single clause.

> It was her mother who did the washing
>   Her mother did the washing

“It was ‘kill or be killed’” is not such a construction.